# How to call this function when the user clicks on my iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to design my own content locker:

page demo: http://testingwebhosts.net16.net/contentlockertest.html

When the user clicks on the iFrame inside the popup I want the page to wait 60 seconds then make the popup go away, ie call the function "removegateway." How do I do that? (note, the submit button and email box are in an iFrame)

Here is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Katy Perry New Single!</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="California Solar, Solar Energy, Solar Installation" />
<meta name="description" content="If you live in California, you may qualify for a massive tax refund just for having solar panels installed in your home! Check if you qualify here! There's no harm in asking! :)" />
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var Delay = 10;//Seconds after them clicking the link, the gateway vanishes. 

function setupgateway()
{
    var Left = $(window).width() /2;
    Left = Left - $('#gatewaydiv').width()/2;

    var Top = $(window).height() /2;
    Top = Top - $('#gatewaydiv').height()/2;

    $('#gatewaydiv').css('top', Top+'px').css('left', Left+'px').css('display', 'inline');
    $('#gatewayDimmer').width($('html').width());
    $('#gatewayDimmer').height($('html').height());
    $('#gatewayDimmer').css('display','block');
}

function removegateway()
{
    $('#gatewaydiv').css('display', 'none');
    $('#gatewayDimmer').css('display','none');
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.offerlink').click(function()
    {
        setTimeout('removegateway()', Delay*1000);
    });

    setupgateway();
});
</script>
<style>

body
{
    background-image:url('http://s21.postimg.org/kzsg5iz7b/Ryan_Coleman.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

#mainContent
{
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:30px;
    width:700px;
    border:3px solid #CDCDCD;
    text-align:center;
}

#gatewaydiv
{
    background-image:url("");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    padding:20px;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:solid 4px gray;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial;
}

#gatewaydiv h1
{
    font-size:35px;
    color:#cc0000;
}

#gatewayMessage
{
    font-size:18px;
}

.offerlink
{
    color:red;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#OfferList
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#OfferList
{
    list-style:none;
}

#gatewayDimmer
{
    background-color:#000000;
    opacity:0.8;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}


</style>
    <style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="gatewayDimmer">
</div>

<div id="gatewaydiv">
<ul id="OfferList">
<h1>Test</h1>
<span id="gatewayMessage">thisisatest</span>
Thank you!
    <iframe id=frame class="offerlink" src="http://ntysr.com/190492/15956&s1=bitch&s2=bitch" scrolling="no" width="80%" width="100%" height="30%" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
    <p>Click <a href="http://trkur5.com/190492/23800">here</a>! (Your browser does not support iframes)</p>
</iframe>
</div>
<script>
var wind = window.location.href; ///?s1={OrderItemId}&s2={QueryString}
var rand = Math.random();
var key = Math.floor((rand*100000000000));
var urlLength = wind.length;
var k = false;
for (i = 0; i < wind.length; i++) {
   if ((wind.charAt(i)=='?') && (wind.charAt(i+1)=='s') && (wind.charAt(i+2)=='1'))   {k=true;}
   if (k) {
      document.getElementById("frame").src =
      document.getElementById("frame").src+wind.charAt(i);
   }
}
if (k==true) {document.getElementById("frame").src = document.getElementById("frame").src+"&s3="+key;}

if (k==false) {document.getElementById("frame").src = document.getElementById("frame").src+"?s3="+key;}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be somewhat annoying if you had to wait 10 seconds after clicking a button before anything happened? Also, jQuery 1.4.2 is like 6-7 years old ?

Comment: @adeneo Did you look at his site? it's one of those "Complete this survey now!" and then takes you to some other site that doesn't even matter. Helping? I am not.

Comment: Unless you have control over the form that is IN that iFrame, you can't do anything with it.  It is, after all, a completely separate entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an .onsubmit event to handle submission like this:

```
$( "#yourform" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  setTimeout('removegateway()', 10000);
});
```